# Ng2-NoUISlider getting same range values

Tags: angular, typescript, nouislider

I'm tring to use multiple sliders on the same page but for some reason all slider gets the same range as the first slider range values. This is my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let property of comepleteFilters">
                <h5>{{property.propertyName}}</h5>
                <div *ngIf="setSliderValues(property); else renderCheckbox">

                  <nouislider #slider [min]="minSliderValue" [max]="maxSliderValue" [step]="stepSliderValue" [config]="conf" [tooltips]="[true, true]" (end)="onSliderChange($event)"></nouislider>

                </div>
```

And my this is my ts file:

```
conf: any = {
    start: [0, 10],
    behaviour: 'drag'
  };
```

..
..

```
  setSliderValues(sliderFilter: FilterList) {
    if (sliderFilter.propertyName === 'enginePower' || sliderFilter.propertyName === 'wheelBase') {
      this.minSliderValue = sliderFilter.propertyValues[0];
      this.maxSliderValue = sliderFilter.propertyValues[sliderFilter.propertyValues.length - 1];
      this.stepSliderValue = 5;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
```

For example the first slider has values between 0-730 and second slider values 2300-12000. But both slider ends up with the range values of 0-730. I even tried to hard code to sliders with different values instead of looping to see if the outcome would be different but I still get the same problem. I'm using Angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the same min and max values. When setSliderValues() function is called, you set one value to max and min. `this.minSliderValue` always gets the value from the last `*ngFor` loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let property of comepleteFilters">
   <h5>{{property.propertyName}}</h5>
   <div *ngIf="setSliderValues(property); else renderCheckbox">
     <nouislider #slider [min]="property.propertyValues[0]" [max]="property.propertyValues[sliderFilter.propertyValues.length - 1]" [step]="stepSliderValue" [config]="conf" [tooltips]="[true, true]" (end)="onSliderChange($event)"></nouislider>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not it. Even if I hardcode 2 sliders like this it'll give the same problem:

```
<nouislider #slider [min]="0" [max]="730" [step]="10" [config]="conf" [tooltips]="[true, true]"></nouislider>
<nouislider #slider [min]="2300" [max]="12000" [step]="100" [config]="conf" [tooltips]="[true, true]"></nouislider>
```

Only the step is working correctly.

I just noticed that the issue is related to me using the same config variable. If I use 2 different configs, with the same values, it works. I'm I missing something?